# Placing an imageview on a Camera Preview mode using a Viewgroup

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using Google's example for using CameraPreview Mode by using it in a ViewGroup. I like the idea of it, but I am trying to place views on top of it and the Camera always supersedes it. I removed the Camera to see my image below it (meaning the view is being added, it is just being added beneath the Camera, even though I place the Camera beneath the Image AND call bringChildToFront(myImageView) a million times.

```
public class CameraPreview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private final String TAG = "Preview";

SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
SurfaceHolder mHolder;
Size mPreviewSize;
List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
Camera mCamera;
private DrawOnTop mDraw;
public ImageView myImageView;


 CameraPreview(Context context) {
    super(context);
    myImageView = new ImageView(context);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
    myImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
    addView(mSurfaceView,0);
    addView(myImageView,1); 


    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);



    Log.d("",drawable+"");
    bringChildToFront(myImageView);
    debug(2);
}

public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    mCamera = camera;
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        requestLayout();
    }

    bringChildToFront(myImageView);

}

public void switchCamera(Camera camera) {
   setCamera(camera);
   try {
       camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
   } catch (IOException exception) {
       Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
   }
   Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
   parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
   requestLayout();

   camera.setParameters(parameters);
   mSurfaceView.setBottom(0);
    bringChildToFront(myImageView);

}
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw.
    try {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        }
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
    }
    bringChildToFront(myImageView);

}
....
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer is ViewGroup works from bottom up. Meaning that 0 is in fact the top most exposed view and not the bottom. I switched the order from:

```
addView(mSurfaceView,0);
addView(myImageView,1);
```

To:

```
addView(myImageView, 0);
addView(mSurfaceView, 1);
```

And it put the image on top. I spent way too much time working on this for that simple of an answer.